# Como relacionar un 'Objeto' a varios 'Objetos' Foreigkey

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Pidiendo de su apoyo nuevamente, estoy haciendo una aplicación para inventariar los puertos eléctricos y ópticos de varios equipos, y no me queda claro como relacionar un modelo con varios modelos.

Tengo los siguientes dos objetos:

```
class ITarjeta(models.Model):
    tipo_tarjeta = models.ForeignKey('catalogo.Tarjeta')
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    etiqueta = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    equipo = models.ForeignKey(IEquipo)

    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Tarjetas"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nomenclatura)

class ISwitch(models.Model):
    tipo_switch = models.ForeignKey('catalogo.Switch')
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    etiqueta = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    rack = models.ForeignKey(IRack)

    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Switc's"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.nomenclatura)
```

Y también e creado otros dos objetos mas que son los que quiero relacionar:

```
class IPuertoOptico(models.Model):
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    equipo = models.ForeignKey(ITarjeta) //tambien lo quiero relacionar con ISwtch

    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
    null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Puertos Opticos en Equipos"

    def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.nomenclatura)


class IPuertoElectrico(models.Model):
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    equipo = models.ForeignKey(ITarjeta) //tambien lo quiero relacionar con ISwtch


    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Puertos Electricos en Equipos"

    def __str__(self):
            return '%s' % (self.nomenclatura)
```

Decidí relacionar los puertos con los equipos ya que los equipos pueden tener muchos puertos, pero un puerto solo puede tener un equipo.El problema viene cuando quiero relacionar el modelo 'IPuertoElectrico' a los modelos 'ISwitch' y 'ITarjeta'.

Alguien me puede orientar de cual es la mejor forma de realizar estas relaciones.

Saludos.

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que viene? Porque nada impide que agregues esas claves foráneas a tus modelos `IPuertoOptico` y `IPuertoElectrico`. Ambos ya tienen dos campos con claves foráneas y fácilmente pueden tener tres. ¿Los modelos `Tarjeta` y `Switch` tienen alguna restricción o dependencia que impidan que se usen al mismo tiempo?

Comment: Gracias toledano, relaciones polimórficas era lo que buscaba pero no supe especificarlo en la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es poder usar una misma ForeignKey que apunte a multiples modelos es posible. Me imagino que un `IPuertoElectrico` solo puede apuntar a una `Tarjeta` o un `Switch`.

Lo que toledano te sugiere es factible, tendrías dos columnas, una apuntando a `ITarjeta` y otra a `ISwitch`, solo que siempre una de ellas sera `NULL` y al querer halar datos tendrás que ver cual de ellas es la válida. Ademas de agregar lógica a tu aplicación para que no permita asignar el objeto a un switch y una tarjeta simultáneamente.

Para usar una misma ForeignKey que pueda apuntar a mas de un modelo puedes utilizar las ForeignKey Genéricas del Framework de Tipos de Contenidos de Django. También conocidas como relaciones polimórficas. ([documentacion](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/contrib/contenttypes/))

En tu archivo de settings.py de tu proyecto, asegurate de tener instalada la app de contenttypes

```
#settings.py

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'otra_aplicacion',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'mira_otra_aplicacion',
)
```

En tus modelos harías los siguientes cambios.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType

class IPuertoOptico(models.Model):
    nomenclatura = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    # ---------------- #
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    # ---------------- #

    autor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    fecha_hora_alta = models.DateTimeField(
        null=True, blank=True, default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Puertos Opticos en Equipos"

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.nomenclatura)
```

El campo `content_type` guarda el id del tipo de modelo que estas relacionando. Esto apunta a un registro de la tabla `django_content_type` de tu base de datos. Si la abres ahí podrás encontrar cada modelo registrado en tu proyecto. En resumen le dice a Django que modelo vamos a usar para la relación.

El campo `object_id` guarda el id del objeto que estas relacionando, esto apunta a un registro dentro de la tabla del objeto relacionado.  En resumen le decimos a Django que registro en especifico del modelo estamos relacionando.

El campo `content_object` es donde declaramos la relación en si y en la cual pasamos los nombres de los dos campos anteriores.

Ejemplo, vamos a asociar una ITarjeta y un ISwitch a dos IPuertoOptico:

Importamos los modelos

```
>>> from tu_aplicacion.models import ITarjeta, ISwitch, IPuertoOptico
```

Conseguimos los puertos opticos, aqui asumimos que existen los ids 1 y 2.

```
>>> puerto_1 = IPuertoOptico.objects.get(id=1)
>>> puerto_2 = IPuertoOptico.objects.get(id=2)
```

Conseguimos la tarjeta y switch. Tambien asumimos que existen los ids 1

```
>>> tarjeta = ITarjeta.objects.get(id=1)
>>> switch = ISwitch.objects.get(id=1)
```

Asociamos los objetos.

```
>>> puerto_1.content_object = tarjeta
>>> puerto_1.save()
>>> puerto_1.content_object
<ITarjeta: tu_nomenclatura>

>>> puerto_2.content_object = switch
>>> puerto_2.save()
>>> puerto_2.content_object
<ISwitch: tu_nomenclatura>
```

Si te fijas ahora solo debemos pasar la instancia del objeto que deseamos relacionar y voila! queda relacionado sin importar el tipo de objeto que sea. Dependiendo de la complejidad de tu sistema es posible que sea necesario agregar otras configuraciones.

Comment: Gracias Fermin, relaciones polimórficas es lo que buscaba hacer en Django pero no sabia cual era la mejor forma, ForeignKey Genéricas fue buena solucion.

Comment: Hola Fermin, Consulta: como se puede hacer para  object_id en Admin se autorellene con los ID de la tabla seleccionada en object_type.